# linux read from file in while loop; command not found

Tags: linux, command

I am reading text from a file to use in a while loop as a variable. The code I am working on is from elsewhere (I am not very familiar with linux) and should work fine, so I think the problem must be in the text file I am supplying.

```
#!/bin/bash

/path.../fulllist.txt | while IFS= read -r sub ; do
```

fulllist.txt is text file with a single entry:

TEST

I get the error:

fulllist.txt: line 1: 'TEST': command not found

I have tried with quotes, backslash etc. and checked the docs for the relevant functions but really cant figure this out. Putting echos around has isolated the above line of code as the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to execute `fulllist.txt` as a command and pipe its output to the `while` loop. You should be redirecting input from the file.

```
while IFS= read -r sub ; do
    # commands
done < /path.../fulllist.txt
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Is there any circumstance in which the original code would work? I don't understand how it was working for them

Comment: Only if you like cats  (cat file | while read ...)